# How to zoom in/out the camera to a target object smooth with lerp with or without tracking the target object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have two modes.

1. tracking the transform object the script is attached to. in this mode just like the script code is now , the targetCamera will keep change the position and lookat the transform when I rotate the transform.
2. the second mode is not tracking the transform. while rotating the transform the camera should stay in place and not changing position and not lookat the transform all the time in the LateUpdate.

the problem is with the second mode: to make the second mode I tried to add a check in the LateUpdate and checking if isRotating false:

```
private void LateUpdate()
{
    if (rotateDice.isRotating == false)
    {
        // Calculate the new target position
        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position + initialDirection * distanceToMove;

        // Smoothly interpolate to the target position
        targetCamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(targetCamera.transform.position, targetPosition, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Make sure the camera is still looking at the object
        targetCamera.transform.LookAt(transform.position);
    }
}
```

the problem with adding this checking to the LateUpdate is that now when i change the slider value it will make a "jump" when the camera change it's position. and i want like in the first mode that when i change the slider value that the camera will smoothly lerp to the new position and lookat but when i rotate the dice object the transform that it will not keep tracking it.  only when changing the slider value.

the full code for the zoom in/out:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using Unity.VisualScripting;

public class CameraZoomSlider : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera targetCamera; // Assign this in the inspector
    public Slider zoomSlider; // Assign this in the inspector
    public float minDistance = 5f; // Minimum distance from the object
    public float maxDistance = 15f; // Maximum distance from the object
    public RotateDice rotateDice;
    public float smoothSpeed = 2f; // Speed at which the camera zooms in/out

    private Vector3 initialDirection;
    private float distanceToMove;

    void Start()
    {
        if (targetCamera == null || zoomSlider == null || rotateDice == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CameraZoomSlider requires references to the camera, slider, and rotateDice.");
            return;
        }

        // Calculate initial direction and distance from the target object
        initialDirection = (targetCamera.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
        distanceToMove = (targetCamera.transform.position - transform.position).magnitude;

        // Setup the slider
        zoomSlider.minValue = minDistance;
        zoomSlider.maxValue = maxDistance;
        zoomSlider.value = distanceToMove;
        zoomSlider.onValueChanged.AddListener(OnSliderValueChanged);

        // Add EventTrigger component to the slider if it doesn't exist
        EventTrigger trigger = zoomSlider.gameObject.GetComponent<EventTrigger>() ?? zoomSlider.gameObject.AddComponent<EventTrigger>();

        // Create PointerDown entry
        EventTrigger.Entry pointerDownEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        pointerDownEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerDown;
        pointerDownEntry.callback.AddListener((data) => { OnPointerDown((PointerEventData)data); });
        trigger.triggers.Add(pointerDownEntry);

        // Create PointerUp entry
        EventTrigger.Entry pointerUpEntry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
        pointerUpEntry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerUp;
        pointerUpEntry.callback.AddListener((data) => { OnPointerUp((PointerEventData)data); });
        trigger.triggers.Add(pointerUpEntry);
    }

    private void OnSliderValueChanged(float distance)
    {
        distanceToMove = distance;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Calculate the new target position
        Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position + initialDirection * distanceToMove;

        // Smoothly interpolate to the target position
        targetCamera.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(targetCamera.transform.position, targetPosition, smoothSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        // Make sure the camera is still looking at the object
        targetCamera.transform.LookAt(transform.position);
    }

    private void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
    {
        rotateDice.isRotating = false;
    }

    private void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
    {
        rotateDice.isRotating = true;
    }
}
```

and the script for the rotation using the mouse:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateDice : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float torque = 50.0f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public bool isRotating = true;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if ((isRotating))
        {
            rb.AddTorque(Vector3.up * torque * -Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
            rb.AddTorque(Vector3.right * torque * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y"));
        }
    }
}
```